# Responsive 3-column layout all messed up after infinite scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a responsive fixed three column fixed-width column layout with variable height depending div content length. The divs stack nicely always in 3 columns. Now I built in infinite scrolling with divs from about 6-7 other pages and it works. However, my layout suddenly got all messed up and showing suddenly 9 columns. I cant see why.

HTML home page:

```
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Articles base</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="scroll-container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="well">
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                        "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/d.jpg">

                        <h3>Article title</h3>

                        <p>la la la la</p></a>

                        <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="well">
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                        "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/d.jpg">

                        <h3>Article title</h3>

                        <p>la la la la la</p></a>

                        <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="well">
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                        "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/d.jpg">

                        <h3>Article title</h3>

                        <p>la la la la la</p></a>

                        <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="well">
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                        "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/k.jpg">

                        <h3>Article title</h3>

                        <p>la la la la la</p></a>

                        <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="well">
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                        "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/l.jpg">

                        <h3>Article title</h3>

                        <p>la la la</p></a>

                        <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="well">
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                        "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/d.jpg">

                        <h3>Article title</h3>

                        <p>la la la la la</p></a>

                        <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="well">
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                        "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/d.jpg">

                        <h3>Article title</h3>

                        <p>la la la</p></a>

                        <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="well">
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                        "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/i.jpg">

                        <h3>Article title</h3>

                        <p>la la la</p></a>

                        <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="well">
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                        "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/d.jpg">

                        <h3>Article title</h3>

                        <p>la la la la</p></a>

                        <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="well">
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                        "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/a.jpg">

                        <h3>Article title</h3>

                        <p>la la la</p></a>

                        <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="well">
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                        "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/z.jpg">

                        <h3>Article title</h3>

                        <p>la la la</p></a>

                        <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="well">
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                        "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/d.jpg">

                        <h3>Article title</h3>

                        <p>la la la!</p></a>

                        <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- These are all the links that can be loaded. -->

    <div id="pages">
        <a href="index.html"></a> <a href="index2.html"></a> <a href=
        "index3.html"></a> <a href="index4.html"></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PAGE 2 and 3,4,5, etc HTML:

```
    <div class="row" id="scroll-container">
        <div id="content">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                    "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/e.jpg">

                    <h3>Article title</h3>

                    <p>kiii kiii</p></a>

                    <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                    "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/k.jpg">

                    <h3>Article title</h3>

                    <p>la la la la</p></a>

                    <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                    "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/m.jpg">

                    <h3>Article title</h3>

                    <p>la la la la</p></a>

                    <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                    "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/k.jpg">

                    <h3>Article title</h3>

                    <p>kiii kiii</p></a>

                    <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                    "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/l.jpg">

                    <h3>Article title</h3>

                    <p>la la la la!!!</p></a>

                    <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt=
                    "Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="images/d.jpg">

                    <h3>Article title</h3>

                    <p>co co co co co co co co co</p></a>

                    <h4>Author and publish date</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing:  border-box !important;}


.row {
 -moz-column-width: 25em;
 -webkit-column-width: 25em;
 -moz-column-gap: 1em;
 -webkit-column-gap:1em; 

}

.row >.col-md-4 {
 display: inline-block;
 padding:  .33rem;
 width:  100%; 
 float:none;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //location.href = 'index.html#start';
    var pages = new Array(); 
    var current = 0; 
    var loaded = new Array(); 

    $('#pages a').each(function(index) {
        pages[index] = $(this).attr('href');
        loaded[$(this).attr('href')] = 0; 
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(e){
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 300) {
            console.log("bottom of the page reached!");
            loaded[pages[current+1]] = loaded[pages[current+1]] + 1; 

            if(loaded[pages[current+1]] <= 1)
                loadMoreContent(current+1);
        }
    });

    function loadMoreContent(position) {
        if(position < pages.length) {
            $('#loader').fadeIn('slow', function() {
                $.get(pages[position], function(data) {
                    $('#loader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                        $('#scroll-container').append(data).fadeIn(999);
                        current=position;
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I solved the columns issue, its back to 3-columns consistently. However, somehow the padding between the divs is now messed up when scrolling down or up (refresh respects the padding again somehow). In the latest Firefox the divs overlap slightly and in the latest Chrome, the divs get cut off at both sides but the padding is respected. I cant explain it or correct it.

Comment: Could you create a playground version like jsfiddle or codepen. It's too much code here.